# RCA to VGA converter

Tags: television, video-adapters, home-electronics, set-top-box

I have a VGA monitor and want to use it with a set-up box that only has RCA output. I want a converter that is RCA to VGA.

I have been unable to find anything likely to work. I have found VGA to RCA converters, but I doubt that they will work in reverse way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=6025&gclid=Cj0KCQjwnqzWBRC_ARIsABSMVTP-jUPQ3B4ndYqlcVnv3dWmlvPr0cfSrBMbxAA5kF8WSF5Fo8EazTUaAndhEALw_wcB#QuestionsandAnswers) is probably what you're looking for.  In the Q/A section, they mention specifically going to VGA from an RCA connection.   You may need gender changers, available on the same site, depending on what cables you already have.